# sending multiple parameters on checkbox submit rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble getting multiple parameters to be submitted when I use a checkbox submit. How would I send both parameters?

I have two items in each row in a table, the columns are "product revenue" and "product title" and I use a check box on each row to select it and then on submit I'd like to send both of these values to the controller. I can get one item working, but wasn't able to figure out how to send the second item as well
I tried using a hidden field, but I couldn't get that working.

View Code

```
<%= form_tag add_multiple_path, method: :post do %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'price_test_datum[product_title][]', p.dimensions[0] %>
    <% hidden_field_tag('price_test_datum[product_price][]', p.metrics[0].values[0]) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Add selected" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller Code (only for one item at the moment since both params aren't being sent)

```
def add_multiple
params[:price_test_datum][:product_title].each {|p| PriceTestDatum.create(product_title: p) }
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to price_test_data_path }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end
```

Parameters sent:
    {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token here", "price_test_datum"=>
    {"product_title"=>["Widget 1", "Widget 2"]}, "commit"=>"Add selected"}

Comment: Check out that `<%` before your `hidden_field_tag`. It seems lonely for an `=`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When I use the <%= the hidden field shows up in params sent, but for some reason it dumps all the values in the column for product revenue?

Comment: That's really a separate question, isn't it? Accept this one and ask a new one and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I accepted your answer, I'll have to wait about an hour before I can post another question however. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing. Also, when you post, please provide detail about what's in your `p` variable (where you say `p.metrics[0].values[0]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your original question (before your correction), you're missing an `=` here:

```
<% hidden_field_tag('price_test_datum[product_price][]', p.metrics[0].values[0]) %>
```

It should be:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag('price_test_datum[product_price][]', p.metrics[0].values[0]) %>
```